# Creating a Scheduled Event in Discord | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

With Discord recently adding `GuildScheduledEvent`s to their API, I wanted to make a bot that can create events (on SlashCommand), but I can't get the whole `GuildScheduledEvent` and `GuildScheduledEventManager` to work.

I keep getting errors like this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')
    at new CachedManager (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\CachedManager.js:21:64)
    at new GuildScheduledEventManager (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildScheduledEventManager.js:17:5)
    at Object.execute (C:\dev\Discord Bots\better bot\bot-data\commands\cancel_film.js:11:31)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Discord Bots\better bot\main.js:44:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:354:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:238:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\dev\Discord Bots\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
```

I know where it gets the error, but I don't understand why.

This is the code from the SlashCommand:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, GuildScheduledEventManager, GuildScheduledEventPrivacyLevel, GuildScheduledEventEntityType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('test_command')
        .setDescription('a test command')
    async execute(interaction) {
        const event_manager = new GuildScheduledEventManager('1039213773216546939')

        await event_manager.create({
            name: 'Test Event',
            scheduledStartTime: new Date(1687284000000),
            privacyLevel: GuildScheduledEventPrivacyLevel.GuildOnly,
            entityType: GuildScheduledEventEntityType.Voice,
            description: 'This is a test Scheduled Event',
            channel: '1118952214774419569',
            image: null,
            reason: 'Testing with creating a Scheduled Event'
        });
    }
}
```

(I am using Node.js btw)

Is there anybody that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the `GuildScheduledEventManager` constructor accepts a guild and `1039213773216546939` is a guild ID(?), not a guild object.

Inside the constructor, [`super` is called with `guild.client`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/managers/GuildScheduledEventManager.js#L16). As your guild is a string, its `client` property is `undefined` and you pass this `undefined` to `CachedManager`. In the `CachedManager`'s constructor, it can't read the `options` property of `undefined` so it throws *"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')"*.

To fix this, you need to pass down a guild instead. You can get it from [`interaction.client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds):

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('test_command')
    .setDescription('a test command'),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const guildID = '1039213773216546939';
    const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.find(guildID);
    
    if (!guild)
      return console.log('Guild not found');

    const event_manager = new GuildScheduledEventManager(guild);

    await event_manager.create({
      name: 'Test Event',
      scheduledStartTime: new Date(1687284000000),
      privacyLevel: GuildScheduledEventPrivacyLevel.GuildOnly,
      entityType: GuildScheduledEventEntityType.Voice,
      description: 'This is a test Scheduled Event',
      channel: '1118952214774419569',
      image: null,
      reason: 'Testing with creating a Scheduled Event',
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Note: `const guild = interaction.client.guilds.cache.find(guildID);` has to be `const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID);` (for me), otherwise it doesn't work.
(Herefor, with executing the command, you do also need to give the client object.)